# Can removing obsolete packages harm a Ubuntu server?

Tags: server, upgrade, xubuntu

If this is true, what are the instances? Are there particular steps needed to be taken when dealing with servers while upgrading systems?

Comment: Are you upgrading your system, and if so, how is this related to removing obsolete packages? Could you give a bit of background or more explanation?

Comment: Yes, I'm upgrading my system to Ubuntu 18.04. At the end, it asks to remove a number of obsolete packages. I just want to be certain if removing them won't cause any issues. And if so how can you do this later on? Is "sudo apt-get autoremove " enough for this purpose?

Comment: No, it shouldn't cause any issues. Yes, you can also autoremove them later.

Answer (score 1):

As [@GabrielaGarcia](https://askubuntu.com/users/880592/gabrielagarcia) said in a comment, this should not cause any issues. These packages are unused and unnecessary, and can be removed without any issue.

Edit: Yes, `sudo apt autoremove` (or `apt-get autoremove`) will also autoremove obsolete packages similar to this automatic prompt when upgrading.